# How to change key value based on comparison of array of objects in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, compare, key, key-value

I have two arrays in jQuery as below.

```
var arr1 = [{A: "t1"},{A: "t3"}];

var arr2 = [{A: "t1",B:""},{A: "t2",B:""},{A: "t3",B:""},{A: "t4",B:""},{A: "t5",B:""},{A: "t6",B:""}];

var arr3 = []; //Only for output
```

Now, the output in arr3 should be:

- all the values from arr2
- the 'B' key should be **Yes** if 'A' key exists
  in arr1
- the 'B' key should be **No** if 'A' key doesn't exist
  in arr1

So, the output I want in arr3 should be:

```
arr3 = [{A: "t1",B:"Yes"},{A: "t2",B:"No"},{A: "t3",B:"Yes"},{A: "t4",B:"No"},{A: "t5",B:"No"},{A: "t6",B:"No"}];
```

This is what I have tried so far

```js
var arr1 = [{A: "t1"},{A: "t3"}];
var arr2 = [{A: "t1",B:""},{A: "t2",B:""},{A: "t3",B:""},{A: "t4",B:""},{A: "t5",B:""},{A: "t6",B:""}];
var arr3 = []; //Only for output

arr1.forEach(function(x) {
  arr2.forEach(function(y) {
    if (x.A == y.A) {
      arr3.push({
        A: x.A,
        B: "Yes"
      });
    } else {
      arr3.push({
        A: x.A,
        B: "No"
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr3);
```

```
//Output
0: {A: "t1", B: "Yes"}
1: {A: "t1", B: "No"}
2: {A: "t1", B: "No"}
3: {A: "t1", B: "No"}
4: {A: "t1", B: "No"}
5: {A: "t1", B: "No"}
6: {A: "t3", B: "No"}
7: {A: "t3", B: "No"}
8: {A: "t3", B: "Yes"}
9: {A: "t3", B: "No"}
10: {A: "t3", B: "No"}
11: {A: "t3", B: "No"}
```

Issue here is that it repeats for each item in arr1, and count gets doubled.
I know it should break somewhere between if and else, so that it does not repeat.

I have tried checking below links too, but couldn't get much help.

[filter array of objects based on separate object keys, values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936172/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-separate-object-keys-values)

[js - How to change one key's value based on another key's value in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335208/js-how-to-change-one-keys-value-based-on-another-keys-value-in-array-of-obje)

[Object comparison based on keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115096/object-comparison-based-on-keys)

[compare array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713350/compare-array-of-objects)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And thank you for a very complete question

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was unaware how to add it as a snippet.

Comment: It is the button that looks like `[<>]`

Comment: How long can these arrays become? If not long you can do `arr1.find(o => o.A===x.A);`

Comment: indeed, they are greater than 5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map and find if the arrays are not huge.

Saves a reduce and push

```js
var arr1 = [{ A: "t1" }, { A: "t3" }];
var arr2 = [{ A: "t1", B: ""}, { A: "t2", B: "" }, { A: "t3", B: "" }, { A: "t4", B: "" }, { A: "t5", B: "" }, { A: "t6", B: "" }];
var arr3 = arr2.map(
  item2 => ({
    A: item2.A,
    B: arr1.find(item1 => item1.A === item2.A) ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  }));

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of the `A` values in `arr1` using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), then use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if each of the `A` values in `arr2` is present in that array, using that to decide whether to set `B` to `Yes` or `No`:

```js
var arr1 = [{ A: "t1" }, { A: "t3" }];
var arr2 = [{ A: "t1", B: ""}, { A: "t2", B: "" }, { A: "t3", B: "" }, { A: "t4", B: "" }, { A: "t5", B: "" }, { A: "t6", B: "" }];
var arr3 = []; //Only for output

var arr1values = arr1.reduce((c, v) => c.concat([v.A]), []);

arr2.forEach(function(y) {
  arr3.push({
    A: y.A,
    B: arr1values.includes(y.A) ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  });
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm. Array.reduce() and Array.includes is something new that I learned today. Much appreciated.

Comment: Would be interesting to compare our two answer in some benchmark test for 5000 items

Comment: @mplungjan indeed. I guess it will largely come down to whether `includes` is enough faster than `find` to make up for the `reduce`.